# Cannot connect to MySQL: DBI connect(';host=1;mysql_read_default_group=client','dbops_usr',...) failed

Tags: mysql, alter, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster, pt-online-schema-change

pt-online schema unable to connect slave servers to monitor replica lags, Using below command and getting errors.

```sh
pt-online-schema-change D=Percona,t=abcd_data_Jan,h=dbops.com,u=dbops_usr \
  --ask-pass \
  --max-lag 120 \
  --check-slave-lag 1 \
  --nodrop-old-table \
  --check-interval 10 \
  --alter 'add index idx_created(created)' \
  --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto \
  --chunk-size=10k \
  --progress time,30 \
  --recursion-method="dsn=h=dbops-replica01.adfghc.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com,D=Percona,t=dsns" \
  --execute
```

Error:

> Found 1 slaves:
>
> ip-175-02-1-69 -> dbops-replica01.adfghc.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
>   Cannot connect to MySQL: DBI connect(';host=1;mysql_read_default_group=client','dbops_usr',...) failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '1' (22) at /usr/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 2345.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue with percona-toolkit-3.2.0 , it worked for me with 3.1.0 version . It looks some version issue.